# Find Path entries in linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have a ubuntu machine. On console when I am executing command echo $PATH I am getting below result.

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41/bin:/home/gaurav/tools/apache
-maven-3.0.3/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_71/bin
```

As you can see there are two java in path which are causing problem. I want to remove 1.6 from path but not able to find where it is added. I checked /etc/profile and .bashrc but found nothing for 1.6. How can I find  the which contains path entry for 1.6.

Comment: apart from /etc/profle and ~/.bashrc, also have a look in ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/environment

Answer (score 0):

try looking in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc